# VS code terminal not works as cmd

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmd

I[image]

[image]

above shows the results of the same command in vs code and windows10 cmd respectively. Why those result are different from each other. What are the setting that should I modify to get the same results in vs code?

Comment: Because the first uses Powershell and the second uses cmd.exe. They're not the same thing.

Comment: @KenWhite I am taking a nodeJS course. The course instructor use vs code terminal in macOs to set environment variables (PORT, NODE_ENV). So, I tried to do same thing in windows with respective changes ( using `set` instead of `export`). But it not works for me

Comment: `SET`is an internal command for cmd.exe. It isn't a Powershell command, and you don't set or retrieve environmental variables the same way in PS as you do in cmd. Did you try searching this site for `[powershell] environment variables`?